# Userscript for generating Markdown from Biblegateway.com

Tags: support, bible-quotes

While we're waiting for a proper solution for embedding Bible passages, I created a hacky userscript (my first ever). I've used it for almost a week now and am happy with it. Works on **Firefox** and **Chrome**. No warranty, etc.

### [**Download**](https://github.com/dancek/biblegateway-markdownifier/raw/master/biblegateway_markdownifier.user.js) / [*Review source code*](https://github.com/dancek/biblegateway-markdownifier/blob/master/biblegateway_markdownifier.user.js)

---

The script inserts a textarea below the passage, looking something like this *(screenshot taken before some bugfixes):*

> [image: A screenshot of userscript-modified BibleGateway]

The textarea content is ready for copy-paste, and should look quite nice. Example:

> [**Psalm 23  (MSG)**](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=psalm%2023&version=MSG)  
>    <sup>1-3</sup> God, my shepherd! I don't need a thing.  
>      You have bedded me down in lush meadows,  
>         you find me quiet pools to drink from.  
>      True to your word,  
>         you let me catch my breath  
>         and send me in the right direction.  
>    
>    <sup>4</sup> Even when the way goes through  
>         Death Valley,  
>      I'm not afraid  
>         when you walk at my side.  
>      Your trusty shepherd's crook  
>         makes me feel secure.  
>    
>    <sup>5</sup> You serve me a six-course dinner  
>         right in front of my enemies.  
>      You revive my drooping head;  
>         my cup brims with blessing.  
>    
>    <sup>6</sup> Your beauty and love chase after me  
>         every day of my life.  
>      I'm back home in the house of God  
>         for the rest of my life.

Now, there probably are bugs. I won't promise to fix them, but you can try reporting here or in the [Github issue tracker](https://github.com/dancek/biblegateway-markdownifier/issues). Even better if you can provide fixes.

Comment: Nice script. I forked and made a small modification.

Comment: @JustinY: thanks! I've updated the script, correcting the problems you pointed out!

Comment: Thanks for this!  I have made updates to work with the new layout: https://github.com/scottTomaszewski/biblegateway-markdownifier

Answer (score 6):

This is great -- have you considered listing it on [Stack Apps](http://stackapps.com) on the scripts tab?

https://stackapps.com/?tab=apps

Comment: Done: [Export BibleGatway page content in markdown format](http://stackapps.com/q/2992)

Answer (score 4):

This is awesome. I have forked your version and made a few modifications to the output format. My modified version can be found on the [StackApps](https://stackapps.com/questions/2992/export-biblegatway-page-content-in-markdown-format) site.

Answer (score 2):

Here's [Caleb's version](https://stackapps.com/questions/2992/export-biblegatway-page-content-in-markdown-format):

> **[John 3:16](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=john%203:16&version=NIV)** (NIV)
>   <sup>16</sup> For God so loved the world that he gave his one and only Son, that whoever believes in him shall not perish but have eternal life.

---

Here's [dancek's version](https://github.com/dancek/biblegateway-markdownifier/raw/master/biblegateway_markdownifier.user.js):

> [**John 3:16 (NIV)**](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=john%203:16&version=NIV)
>
> <sup>16</sup>  For God so loved the world that he gave his one and only Son, that whoever believes in him shall not perish but have eternal life.

---

Take your pick!

---

I just got notified on a greasemonkey update, haven't been using this as much as I should, but this is what I get now:

> [**John 3:16 (NIV)**](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=John%203:16&version=NIV)
>
> <sup>16</sup>  For God so lovedA)">  the world that he gaveB)">  his one and only Son,C)">  that whoever believesD)">  in him shall not perish but have eternal life.E)">

Comment: Good stuff, though having looked at the diff I thought there would've been more changes... Perhaps they were only related to the markdown formatting, i.e. not visible to the viewer.

Comment: That looks like a biblegateway format change. You might try it with my script and use the most recent version because I've updated it to clean up some new markup several times.